# Use proper annotation for the BigDecimal

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I have a `POJO` with the Lombok annotation provided below,

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrderDto extends BaseDto {

    @JsonProperty( "products" )
    private final List<String> products;

    @JsonProperty( "basket_items" )
    private final List<BasketItemDto> basketItems;

    @JsonProperty( "timestamp" )
    @MockLocalDateTime( ignoreMillis = true )
    @JsonDeserialize( using = JavaOffsetDateTimeDeserializer.class )
    @JsonSerialize( using = JavaOffsetDateTimeSerializer.class )
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

    @JsonProperty( "amount" )
    @Min( value = 0L)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @JsonProperty( "shop_id" )
    private Integer shopId;

}
```

I would like to take the `amount` field accepts a value above zero. However, when I applied the annotation of `@Min( value = 0L)` and provide the request with a negative amount value, the app doesn't break.

I assume the reason is the `amount` has the type of `BigDecimal` and then I use the `Long` with the annotation.

How do I use the proper annotation to filter the value for a `BigDecimal`?

**Update**

I have tried to use the `@DecimalMin("0.00")` and the app still doesn't break. But, when I provide the `"amount": 05` with leading zero, I get the message,

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "JSON parse error: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.xyz.bbb.dto.request.RequestDto[\"order\"])"
}
```

Comment: Did you add a `@Valid` on your POJO ? For example in a rest controller, as a request body : `@Valid @RequestBody OrderDto orderDto`

Comment: I'm serious not able to break the app and very surprised at the moment. It's a big app, so, I may still need to invest more time.

Comment: did you even try what i'm suggesting ??

Comment: Yea I tried what you suggested

Comment: is your import correct for `@Min`

Comment: according to this doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm you could use `@DecimalMin("0.00")`

Comment: I updated the question. The app only break for the leading zero even I provide the annotation you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Positive annotation of validation-api

Comment: This also doesn't break the app and I'm in the correct place. This is surprising.